# Ionic 3, Googleplus plugin and firebase plugin playservices conflict problem - August 2019

Tags: android, firebase, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have ionic 3 app using firebase and google plus plugins, when I install both plugins and debug android platform it gives an **processDebugResources** error, after seaching as in the [fire-base-plugin issues](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1006) I made changes in firebase plugin and android platform like below , then I can build android platform also firebase working well but google plus not working anymore without any errors or exceptions just waiting fro promise. can anyone help me please?

I have add these line to firebase plugin

```
<framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16+" />
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.+" />
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.+" />
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.+" />
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.+" />
```

and made these chnages in plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/src/android/ build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.+' 
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.+'
```

also I have change andriod platform gradle to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // google-services dependency from cordova-plugin-firebase
```

Comment: try to change the numbers int this file path (just try)
/platforms/android/project.properties
firebase-core:11.4.2/11.8.0
firebase-messaging:11.4.2/11.8.0
firebase-config:11.4.2/11.8.0
firebase-perf:11.4.2/11.8.0
firebase-auth:11.4.2/11.8.0
firebase-iid:11.4.2/11.8.0

Comment: thank you Anandh, when I change it to 11.8.0 it gives me debug error like :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac. dpo you have another idea?

Comment: Try with 11.4.2

Comment: Paste your android.properties files here

Comment: target=android-27
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova-plugin-firebase/needion-build.gradle
com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.4.2
com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.4.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2
com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.4.2
com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+

Comment: >>>>>>>>>it gives the error below;  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

Answer (score 0):

I was solved this like :

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --save --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=com.googleusercontent.apps.************* --variable WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID=*************.apps.googleusercontent.com --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=15.0.1
```

sample code :

var webClientId = '********.apps.googleusercontent.com';

```
this.googlePlus.login({
'webClientId': webClientId,
'offline': false
}).then.........
```